# TypeError: validator is undefined in jquery.validate.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, typeerror

I have following form.

[image]

once I click that **Go to Next Section** Button I can direct to next section in this form.

Here the [whole code](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yqx99/add-new-product) for this view and this the [Layout file](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/EEGnX) for that view page

But now Once I click I'm not getting any response and I cannot goto next page I'm getting following error.But this error occur in Firefox only , once I change debugging to Chrome this is working.

> TypeError: validator is undefined file_path/jquery.validate.js

this is that error view

**Error view 1**

[image]

once I click above view I can see below view

**Error view 2**

[image]

Bugzilla debugger pointed out following section (`[if (validator.settings.rules)]`) of `jquery.validate.js` file has the error

```
staticRules: function( element ) {
    var rules = {};
    var validator = $.data(element.form, "validator");
    if ( validator.settings.rules ) {
        rules = $.validator.normalizeRule(validator.settings.rules[element.name]) || {};
    }
    return rules;
},
```

Comment: Can you please give us the **`source of html`** not server side code?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA [this is the HTML](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yqx99/add-new-product)

Comment: Looking at your layout and the view, your have duplicate scripts all over the place (at least 3 copies of jquery - the last one wipes out the others). Put all you scripts in one place (either in the `<head>` or immediately before the closing `</body>` tags and ensure you have them in the right order and no duplicates

Comment: do I need to remove `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js)` too since that one is an another version of jquery ?

Comment: The scripts in the layout and view are a mess. Use bundles (and don't include the minified versions (bundling will do the minification in production)

Comment: as you mentioned I improved the code here the [new layout file](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yqzpz) , shall I remove all the "..min.js" from here ?

Comment: @kez, Its still a mess. In the head you have `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")` followed by `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")`. Then you add `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")` wiping out all the previous scripts. Then at the bottom you have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` again wiping out all the previous scripts. Start by getting rid of everything in the head. And then read [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed as I you guided , here the [BundleConfig.cs](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/AAo4L/bundle-config-file) and this is the [New Layout File](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yqz6b/new-layout-file-v3)  could you please to let me whether I'm in right path ?

Comment: Looking better. You layout should also have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval");` after `bundles/jquery` if you have not included it in your view. You also need to remove `@Scripts.Render("~/bundle/base")` because that is just duplicating `jquery` and `bootstrap` again. But I would question if you need every bundle in the layout (do you really use `summernote` and `bootstrap_fileinput` in every view?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope. I need `summernote` and `bootstrap_fileinput` for specific views only.for that view pages I refer [that previous Layout file](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yqz6b/new-layout-file-v3)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just debug this using firefox , but once I moved to chrome this this working , is this because of missing tag ?

Comment: @kez are you able to attach your rendered source code of that form page so that we can see where and when your external resources are being referenced and how many duplicates, if any, exist.

Comment: @partypete25 this is that [view page](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yqx99/add-new-product) , this is [layout of previous view page](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/EEGnX) , and this is [BundleConfig.cs](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/AAo4L/bundle-config-file) file

Comment: @kez No i want the rendered source code. So when you load the page in your browser, right click and view page source. Copy and paste that.

Comment: @partypete25 as you said one the load the page in my browser, I right clicked and view page source. and [copied here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/KKGME)

Comment: @kez ok great! Mate, you need to remove the duplicate sources of jquery you are loading into your document. You have included it 5 times, on lines 33, 47, 527, 528, 536. Remove all except for the first one. Then i want you to edit src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js" and replace it with the code from here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: @partypete25 Actually I did as you mentioned but error remains. this is not working with  Firefox , but once I moved to chrome this this working  this is [new page source](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/dRbqo)

Comment: @kez There is still a lot of resources being duplicated. Firstly remove all duplicates. 1) summernote js - 42, 527. 2) summernote css - 25, 62. 3) validate js - 514, 524. 4)validate unobtrusive js - 515, 525. 5) bootstrap js - 35, 517, 520. Secondly, are you supporting ie 8 and below? If so, replace line 518 "respond.js" with this: <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/Scripts/html5shiv.min.js"></script><script src="/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
and thirdly, on line 532, apply your custom script within document ready function
$(function(){//place your javascript here});

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to update your HTML and change `<div class="form-horizontal">` to `<form class="form-horizontal">`. Don't forget to update the closing tag as well.

Comment: Nope same error occur again once I moved to your solution