# ASP.NET Validator missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an ASP.NET project with some views with forms. I wanted to change the trigger for the validation of the inputs. This code is used to trigger the validator on keyup and not out of focus.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $validatr = $('form').data('validator');
    var settngs = $validatr.settings;

    settngs.onkeyup = function (element, eventType) {
        if (!$validatr.element(element))
        {
            $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
        }
    };

    settngs.onfocusout = false;
});
```

**Problem**

On some views I get this error:

```
TypeError: $validatr is undefined, var settngs = $validatr.settings;
```

And the validation error appear only on out of focus.
I tried to get the validator also with this code, but also failed:

```
var $validatr = $('form').validate()
```

The controller, model and views are pretty much the same. Just the names of the inputs changes.

**UPDATE**
If I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $validatr = $('form').validate();
    var settngs = $validatr.settings;
    console.log('settings:'); //I get an output
    console.log(settngs); //I get an output

    settngs.onkeyup = function (element, eventType) {
        console.log(element); //I do not get any message here
        console.log(eventType); //I do not get any message here

        if (!$validatr.element(element)) {
            console.log('if not validator');
            $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
        }
        else {
            console.log('else not validator');
        }
    };

    // onload initial validation
    $("form").validate().elements().each(function () {
        if (!$validatr.element($(this))) {
            console.log($(this)[0].name + ': initial if not validator');
            $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
        }
    });
});
```

This are the settings returned to console:

```
errorClass:"error"
errorContainer:Object[]
errorElement:"label"
errorLabelContainer:Object[]
focusCleanup:false
focusInvalid:true
groups:Object:{}
ignore:":hidden"
ignoreTitle:false
messages:Object:{}
onsubmit:true
rules:Object:{}
validClass:"valid"
highlight:function(element,:errorClass,:validClass)
onclick:function(element)
onfocusin:function(element)
onfocusout:function(element)
onkeyup:function(element,:eventType)
unhighlight:function(element,:errorClass,:validClass)
```

**SOLUTION**

At the end this was the solution:
[MVC 5 Losing validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844505/mvc-5-losing-validator/35845314#35845314)

Comment: I presume you have already read upon following [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796001/typeerror-validator-is-undefined-in-jquery-validate-js). `$('form').data('validator')` will get validator if you have properly initialized jquery and unobtrusive validation. If you are still experiencing an issue, please post more of your code (including layout page, etc.)

Comment: At the end this was the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844505/mvc-5-losing-validator/35845314#35845314

Comment: Great. So the issue was related to multiple forms on the page and narrowing down selector to pick the right form. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment above, JavaScript is case-sensitive, `Validate()` should be `validate()`.

```
var $validatr = $('form').validate();
```

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a80002af/1/). If you use inspect in Chrome, or use FireBug in FireFox, you will see output and no errors in the console.

**Update 1** - I have expanded jsFiddle to simulate your desired effect of validating on `onkeyup`. Let me know if [this jsFiddle works](https://jsfiddle.net/a80002af/5/) for you. I also added initial validation for all elements.

```
// onload initial validation
$("form").validate().elements().each(function(){
  if (!$validatr.element($(this))) {
        console.log($(this)[0].name + ': initial if not validator');
        $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
  }    
});
```

Comment: I do not get any error from the script, but the validation on keyup is not working either.