# MVC 5 Losing validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have noticed a strange behavior in MVC 5 (C#) with the form validator.
This is my code to check on keyup for errors:

```
    var $validatr = $('form').data('validator');
    var settngs = $validatr.settings;

    settngs.onkeyup = function (element, eventType) {
        if (!$validatr.element(element)) {
            $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
        }
    };
    settngs.onfocusout = false;
```

I have noticed that this code works on some forms, on other not. I tried to get the validator also like this:

```
var $validatr = $('form').validate();
```

But it is still not working. **Important:** then I noticed that the the code is working for the registration form only if the user is not logged already. (I can access the registration form also when the user is logged). When the user is logged I get this error:

```
TypeError: $validatr is undefined
```

In this case the error for the input form pops-up only when there is an out_of_focus of the element.

**UPDATE**:

If I delete this cookie: AspNet.ApplicationCookie and refresh the page the user is logged out and the onKeyUp validation is working. What is going on?

Comment: 1. make sure you are loading required JS files. 2. make sure you have `form` element in DOM

Comment: Yes all the JS files are loaded and the form is in DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than one form on a page or you have a popup that contains a form on the page the Jquery selector can have multiple forms targeted the way you are using your selector. I would suggest you target a form by Id instead

```
var $validatr = $('#myForm1').data('validator');
```

Or alternatively using  a loop to target all form elements

```
 $('form').each(function( index, form ) {
    var settngs = form.settings;

    settngs.onkeyup = function (element, eventType) {
        if (!form.element(element)) {
            form.triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
        }
    };
    settngs.onfocusout = false;
});
```

Comment: I had to select the form. When the user was logged in there was an additional form created in the header as link to user_management.